# Ввод матрицы с клавиатуры

Tags: c#, матрицы

После ввода элементов матрицы возникает исключение : "Array does not have that many dimensions.". Как решить эту проблему?

```cs
namespace consolMatrix
{
    class Program
    {
        static Tuple<int, int> MatrixSize()
        {
            int N, M;

            Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность матрицы в виде NxM:");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            while (!input.Contains('x'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Неправильно введена размерность! Формат ввода - NxM: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            string[] inputSplit = input.Split('x');

            N = int.Parse(inputSplit[0]);
            M = int.Parse(inputSplit[1]);

            return Tuple.Create(N, M);
        }
        static float[,] FormMatrix(Tuple<int, int> MatrixSize) 
        {
            float[,] matrix = new float[MatrixSize.Item1, MatrixSize.Item2];

            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize.Item1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите {0} строку, вводя элементы через пробел:", i + 1);
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                string[] inputSplit = input.Split(' ');

                while (inputSplit.Length > MatrixSize.Item2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели слишком много символов! Введите корректное количество:");
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                    inputSplit = input.Split(' ');
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < MatrixSize.Item2; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i, j] = float.Parse(inputSplit[j]);
                }
            }

            return matrix;

        }

        static void PrintMatrix(float[,] matrix)
        {
            int N = matrix.GetLength(0);
            int M = matrix.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) Console.Write("{0} ", matrix[i, j]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        static float[,] MatrixSum(float[,] matrix1, float[,] matrix2)
        {
            if ((matrix1.GetLength(0) == matrix2.GetLength(0)) & (matrix1.GetLength(1) == matrix2.GetLength(2))) // На этой строчке ошибка
            {
                float[,] sumMatrix = new float[matrix1.GetLength(0), matrix1.GetLength(2)];

                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.GetLength(1); j++) sumMatrix[i, j] = matrix1[i, j] + matrix2[i, j];
                }

                return sumMatrix;
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Матрицы не могут быть сложены - отличается их размерность.");
                return matrix1;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tuple<int, int> Matrix1_Size = MatrixSize();
            Tuple<int, int> Matrix2_Size = MatrixSize();

            float[,] matrix1 = FormMatrix(Matrix1_Size);
            float[,] matrix2 = FormMatrix(Matrix2_Size);

            PrintMatrix(matrix1);
            PrintMatrix(matrix2);

            float[,] matrix3 = MatrixSum(matrix1, matrix2);
            PrintMatrix(matrix3);

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Нажмите любую клавишу для выхода из программы");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хоть пометьте эту строчку. Здесь нумерации строк нет, а считать до 67, честно говоря, неохота

Comment: По коду в вопросе не понятно, где находится 67 строка. Укажите конкретно, где в коде у вас возникает ошибка.

Comment: Строка с ошибкой помечена

Comment: `matrix2.GetLength(2)` опечатка? Запрашиваете длину третьего измерения в двухмерном массиве. Еще `&` опечатка, должно быть `&&`. Логическте "и" от побитового надо уметь отличать.

Comment: _Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до публикации вопроса._

Answer (score 0):

Была опечатка в matrix2.GetLength(2), а должно быть matrix2.GetLength(1)